# Flutter GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

How can I make a flutter app that makes a particular action based on swiping in the screen from a point to another and its important that I want the start and end point to be specified
or also can use if you can help me make the swipe in a particular angle and the swipe have to be above or below a certain length
So in short I want I want either
start and end point of the swipe
or angle and length
and I will be so happy if you can do both of them

Comment: You must probably try adding this in fiver or upwork. This is Stack overflow where developers help each other to solve a single focused problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what I want to be able to read the swipe on the screen exactly how it is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
GestureDetector(
      onPanUpdate: (details) {
        // Swiping in right direction.
        if (details.delta.dx > 0) {}

        // Swiping in left direction.
        if (details.delta.dx < 0) {}
      },

      onPanEnd: (details) {
        // User swiped Left
        if (details.primaryVelocity > 0) {}
          
        // User swiped Right
        if (details.primaryVelocity < 0) {}
      },
      child: YourWidget(),
    )
```

Comment: can I make more specific directions like 45 angle

Comment: yes you can, I think it is combination of dx and dy.